# vars: subscript out of range

Tags: scripting, csh

I have a csh script (i know i know) and inside my script i run a sql query i then turn the output into a variable to use in my next command in the script.

essentially it looks like this:

```
set vars = `echo "my sql command"`
set numRows = $#vars
next command '$vars[1]'
.....
```

My logs show the error

```
Vars : subscript out of range
```

Can someone tell what would cause this and how to resolve?

Comment: Print out the values of $vars and $numRows. odds are vars is not being set to what you think it is. also putting single quotes around '$vars[1]' you are passing the string '$vars[1]' to your next command NOT the value of the element at index 1 from vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `next command '$vars[1]'` is the actual command you are using? For
the single quotes won't allow the $vars to be expanded?

In any case, the error that you are seeing `subscript out of range` => $vars does not contain that many elements. That means there is some error in your first statement: set vars = `echo "my sql command"`

what does $#vars show?

Also the first statement is better written as: set vars = (  `echo "my sql command"`  )

Comment: Thanks Rakesh i have found the issue. As you say $vars didnt contain any elements. There is a issue with teh database updating rather then my script so its all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent such incidents when a variable being used does not exist which is the result of command substitution used earlier in the code you can do this.

```
( your_SQL_command > log ) >& /dev/null
if ( $status != 0 || -z log ) then
   echo "Some problem running your SQL command...Bailing out."
   exit 1
endif

set vars = ( "`cat log`" )

# now safe to use the $vars...
your_next_SQL_command "$vars[1]"
```